# Faster way to populate cells in vba

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I am trying to populate 200,000 cells using vba, and it is taking over 5 mins to do it. Is there a faster way to populate the cells? Code is shown below

### Code:

```
Sub pre()

Dim i As Long: i = 2

Dim rex As Variant

For rex = -10 To 10 Step 0.001

Cells(i, 47) = rex
i = i + 1
Next rex
End Sub
```

I guess just to make it easier for you, I'm trying to populate the cells in column AU to go from -10 to 10 and have a change of 0.001 each time

Comment: instead of calculating the cell contents over and over again, calculate them once.  After that, just load the data via the jetdb engine or the xmlhhtprequest, or whatever data fetching mechanism. ...?

Comment: Hmmm.... Is there any other way you would recommend?

Comment: importing a table/data seems fastest. if you must calculate results each time, maybe don't use MS Office? Have u tried Google Sheets in Chrome (that would use the v8 engine) ...just to benchmark / test?

Comment: Load the value into an array then assigned the array as a group to the range as one.

Comment: @ScottCraner can you give me an example of that code?

Comment: I ran your code changed 0.001 to 0.0001, the code took about 3 seconds

Comment: I'm running this on a pretty weak laptop haha maybe that's why

Comment: @Davesexcel what are you using, I have a intel xeon nearly top of the line laptop and I only made it through 1842 iteration before stopping after 20-30 seconds.

Comment: I just have a  lenova, with an i5, about 4 yrs old.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load an array then assign the array to the cells.

```
Sub pre()

    Dim i As Long: i = 1
    Dim arr(1 To 200000, 1 To 1) As Variant
    Dim rex As Variant

    For rex = -10 To 10 Step 0.001
        arr(i, 1) = rex
        i = i + 1
    Next rex

    ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 47).Resize(200000).Value = arr
End Sub
```

accessing the worksheet from vba slows the code.  limit the number of time the worksheet is accessed.

Comment: What in the holy toast!? That's way faster! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

This one runs in about a second

I'll put a timer on it.

OP's code ran in .4101563

The below code runs in .3789063

Scotts code possibly 9/1000 of a second? 9.765625E-02

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Range("AU3:AU200000")
    Range("Au2").Value = -10

    rng.Formula = "=AU2+0.0001"
    rng.Value = rng.Value

End Sub
```

Comment: opening a new workbook and running the op's code it took 0.328125  seconds.  I keep a workbook open for all my stackoverflow answers per day, I don't keep it, but close it at the end of the day.  So I must have had something in the background.  Your took 0.3984375 on my machine.  Mine 0.07421875.